# 1.9 authorize.net direct post fails admin orders

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net, admin-order-create, direct-post

**We setup a fresh install of Magento 1.9.3.4**

We're trying to create admin orders using `Authorize.net` Direct Post and it's not working.

We get an error in the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: transport is not defined

Looking @ the code in `/js/mage/directpost.js` we found on line 309

```
saveAdminOrderSuccess : function(data) {
    var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

    if (response.directpost) {
        this.orderIncrementId = response.directpost.fields.x_invoice_num;
        var paymentData = {};
        for ( var key in response.directpost.fields) {
            if(response.directpost.fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                paymentData[key] = response.directpost.fields[key];
            }
        }
        var preparedData = this.preparePaymentRequest(paymentData);
        this.sendPaymentRequest(preparedData);
    } else {
        if (response.redirect) {
            window.location = response.redirect;
        }
        if (response.error_messages) {
            var msg = response.error_messages;
            if (Object.isArray(msg)) {
                msg = msg.join("\n");
            }
            if (msg) {
                alert(msg.stripTags().toString());
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Something is clearly wrong here, because the variable `data` passed in in `saveAdminOrderSuccess : function(data)` is not being used anywhere in the function.

Has anyone gotten Authorize.net Direct Post to work for admin orders?

Strangely enough, this works just fine on the front end, in that code the functions variable is named `transport`

```
saveOnepageOrderSuccess : function(transport) {
    if (transport.status == 403) {
        checkout.ajaxFailure();
    }
    var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

    if (response.success && response.directpost) {
        this.orderIncrementId = response.directpost.fields.x_invoice_num;
        var paymentData = {};
        for ( var key in response.directpost.fields) {
            if(response.directpost.fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                paymentData[key] = response.directpost.fields[key];
            }
        }
        var preparedData = this.preparePaymentRequest(paymentData);
        this.sendPaymentRequest(preparedData);
    } else {
        var msg = response.error_messages;
        if (Object.isArray(msg)) {
            msg = msg.join("\n");
        }
        if (msg) {
            alert(msg.stripTags().toString());
        }

        if (response.update_section) {
            $('checkout-' + response.update_section.name + '-load').update(response.update_section.html);
            response.update_section.html.evalScripts();
        }

        if (response.goto_section) {
            checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section);
            checkout.reloadProgressBlock();
        }
    }
},
```

I tried switching out `data` for `transport` in the `saveAdminOrderSuccess` function but that didn't help.

Comment: debug mode yes and then check what is issue.

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala the debug mode only collects data from when Magento starts submitting the payment to authorize.net - since the method never goes through, there is no debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @joe wrote above you need to replace
 `var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};`
with:
`var response = data.responseJSON || data.evalJSON(true) || {};`

But, you also need to update the admin helper in app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php

replace
`public function getRedirectIframeUrl($params)
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect', $params);
    }`
with:

```
     public function getRedirectIframeUrl($params)
{
    switch ($params['controller_action_name']) {
        case 'onepage':
            $route = 'authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect';
            break;

        case 'sales_order_create':
        case 'sales_order_edit':
            $route = 'adminhtml/authorizenet_directpost_payment/redirect';
            break;

        default:
            $route = 'authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect';
            break;
    }

    return $this->_getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

This was an oversight by the Magento core team when they updated the module to have two separate helpers for admin and for the front end.

The Proper way of doing this would be to put this in a module, if I have time I will post an update with the module.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by replacing:

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};
```

with:

```
var response = data.responseJSON || data.evalJSON(true) || {};
```

- *Notice that I removed `responseText` as well.*

Comment: you got it to create an order for you?
I tried your edit and it's still now working :(

Comment: Yes. Are you seeing any more console errors? What happens when you try to submit an order?

Comment: Are you getting redirected to `admin_url`sales_order/view/order_id/`order_number`? I'm not